# GCM/FCM push notification using both HTTP and XMPP protocol

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

My understanding of push notification for android is that the OS keeps one active connection to the FCM connection servers. This is what I assumed when my app server only supported the HTTP protocol.

Now, my app also has its own XMPP connection used for instant messaging, presence, etc... usual XMPP stuff. I was thinking about replacing this XMPP connection with the push notification XMPP connection and that's when I got confused.

If I use both the HTTP and XMPP protocols for push notifications, then wouldn't there be two active connections(One to FCM connection server and the other to Cloud Connection Server)? If there are two active connections, then what would be the benefit of using both protocols for push notifications versus using just the HTTP push protocol and keeping my own XMPP connection that I already had?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android device will use the same connection to receive messages sent through HTTP or XMPP. The connection to the CCS server is with your app server not with the device.

Comment: From what I read in the documentations, there seems to be two connections. Also, wouldn't the two protocols be on two different ports? And wouldn't that mean there are two connections?

Comment: The thing to note is that the XMPP connection is not made with the device. The device only connects to FCM thus one connection. The XMPP connection is between your server and CCS (part of FCM)

Comment: does upstream use the same connection also?

Comment: Yes it is the same connection, this is why it is a better use of battery.